# Can't display AggregateList to a datatable

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, soql, lightning-datatable

I am trying to display the results of a query to a `datatable`. I receive the results of the query from the helper, but nothing is displayed, and i don't know why.

Controller:

```
public with sharing class ContactController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<AggregateResult> getAssets() {
        List<AggregateResult> assets = 
                [select License__r.Account__c, License__r.Account__r.Name a, Product2.Name b, sum(limit_1_Value__C)
                    from Asset 
                    Where Limit_1_Name__C = 'Users'
                    AND License__r.Account__c != null
                    AND product2Id != null
                    group by License__r.Account__c,License__r.Account__r.Name,Product2.Name
                    LIMIT 1000
                    ];

        System.debug('assets: ' + assets);
        return assets;
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
<aura:component controller="ContactController"  implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,force:hasSObjectName" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="mydata" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.init }"/>
    <lightning:datatable data="{! v.mydata }" 
        columns="{! v.mycolumns }" 
        keyField="Id"
        hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
   init: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        cmp.set('v.mycolumns', [
                {label: 'Account Id', fieldName: 'Id', type: 'text'},
                {label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
                {label: 'Asset Name', fieldName: 'Asset', type: 'text'},
                {label: 'Count', fieldName: 'Count', type: 'text'}
            ]);
        helper.getData(cmp);
    },
})
```

Helper:

```
({
    getData : function(cmp) {
        var action = cmp.get('c.getAssets');
        action.setCallback(this, $A.getCallback(function (response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                cmp.set('v.mydata', response.getReturnValue());
            } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                console.error(errors);
            }
        }));
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

})
```

Comment: Please do not include supplications for help in your posts, nor add thanks. Thank us by continuing to contribute to the quality standards here and remembering that the format here is *question* and answer. Saying "Please help" is not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For AggregateResult, the fieldName must match the *alias* for the field, if any, or `exprX` (where X is a number starting with 0 for the leftmost element). I advise you add aliases:

```
[select License__r.Account__c licenseAccountId, License__r.Account__r.Name licenseAccountName, Product2.Name productName, sum(limit_1_Value__C) count
```

And then update your fieldName values:

```
{label: 'Account Id', fieldName: 'licenseAccountId', type: 'text'},
{label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'licenseAccountName', type: 'text'},
{label: 'Asset Name', fieldName: 'productName', type: 'text'},
{label: 'Count', fieldName: 'count', type: 'text'}
```

Remember that Lightning is Case Sensitive, so they should match exactly.